# android 4 - Dialog Fragment - NullPointer Exception

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I have a problem with Android 4 and my Dialog Fragments. I can open the `Dialogs` but if i cancel the Dialog or submit it every time i get a `NullPointerException`. In newer Android versions like 5 or 6 everything works great.
It´s so annoying. Why google why??? I searched multiple days and tested some things out but i can't get this to work.

```
public class BirthdatePickerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

//region Variables



//Listener Object
private BirthdatePickerDialogFragment.OnCompleteBabyBirthdateListener setDateListener;

Context sourceActivityContext = null;

//endregion



@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    String savedBirthdateString = SharedPreferenceHelper.getSharedPreferenceString(sourceActivityContext,SharedPreferenceHelper.Birthdate,"");

    int year = 0;
    int month = 0;
    int day = 0;


    if(savedBirthdateString != "")
    {
        String[] splitBirthdateString = savedBirthdateString.split("\\.");


        int strYear = Integer.parseInt(splitBirthdateString[2]);
        int strMonth = (Integer.parseInt(splitBirthdateString[1])) - 1 ; 
        int strDay = Integer.parseInt(splitBirthdateString[0]);

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(strYear,strMonth,strDay);


         year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
         month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
         day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    }        
    else{
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
         year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
         month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
         day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    }

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
    String strYear =  String.valueOf(year);
    String strDayOfMonth = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
    String strMonth = String.valueOf(month + 1);

    setDateListener.onCompleteBirthDatePicker(MessageFormat.format("{0}.{1}.{2}", strDayOfMonth, strMonth, strYear));
}


public static interface OnCompleteBabyBirthdateListener {
    public abstract void onCompleteBirthDatePicker(String babyBirthDate);

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    try {
        this.setDateListener = (BirthdatePickerDialogFragment.OnCompleteBabyBirthdateListener)context;
        this.sourceActivityContext = context;
    }
    catch (final ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement OnCompleteListener");
    }      

}
```

}

This is the birth date dialog. It opens but if i submit or cancel the Exception gets thrown.
I hope someone could help me.
Exceptionlog:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              java.lang.NullPointerException
                  at com.jalbmagic.test.Dialogs.BirthdatePickerDialogFragment.onDateSet(BirthdatePickerDialogFragment.java:93)
                  at android.app.DatePickerDialog.tryNotifyDateSet(DatePickerDialog.java:148)
                  at android.app.DatePickerDialog.onStop(DatePickerDialog.java:155)
                  at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:326)
                  at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:302)
                  at android.app.Dialog.cancel(Dialog.java:1104)
                  at android.app.Dialog.onTouchEvent(Dialog.java:617)
                  at android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent(Dialog.java:739)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1873)
                  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7307)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3174)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3119)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4155)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4134)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4226)
                  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
                  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
                  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: share us your console

Comment: Can you post your logs so that it could be figured where exactly what is happening? Also can you debug to check what is this returning: `savedBirthdateString` ?

Comment: hey check my updated code

Comment: savedBirthdateString is empty. This is because i dont saved a date bevor  in the sharedpreferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. Since API Level 23 the method onAttach(Activity activity) is exchanged and the new version is onAttach(Context context). 
I tested all the time with Android 6 and implemented only onAttach(Context context) so lower API levels then 23 can´t use this method and i never attached the activity to the fragment. So the problem is clear. After i implemented the old method all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to replace with this**

```
if(!savedBirthdateString.equals(""))
{
    String[] splitBirthdateString = savedBirthdateString.split("\\.");


    int strYear = Integer.parseInt(splitBirthdateString[2]);
    int strMonth = (Integer.parseInt(splitBirthdateString[1])) - 1 ; 
    int strDay = Integer.parseInt(splitBirthdateString[0]);

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(strYear,strMonth,strDay);


     year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
     month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
     day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

}        
else{
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
     year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
     month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
     day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

}
```

Comment: thx for the fast answer. I corrected the if clause but that is not the problem at all. In android 5 and 6 it works well. But again thx :-)